# Desktop backups maintenance on a network share

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, backup

I have configured Windows Backup and Restore function on Windows 7 Professional desktops to make daily backup on a network share placed on a Windows Server 2012. (BTW It's a pity that this utility does not have an option to use currently logged in user's credentials especially Active Directory user's credentials. Instead it is necessary to enter fixed user's credentials. Thus password will not update when changed in Active Directory.) This utility also does not have any maintenance mechanism for automatically removing old backup versions. So it will produce a lot of outdated data quickly filling server's disk space.
Now I have such a situation in directory structure (this is only for one user but there are many other users' folders in 'Users' catalog):

```
Users  
├─agnes.microt  
│   ├─AGNES-PC  
│   │   ├─Backup Set 2014-02-24 060001  
│   │   │   ├─Backup Files 2014-02-24 060001  
│   │   │   ├─Backup Files 2014-02-25 091044  
│   │   │   ├─Backup Files 2014-02-26 092458  
│   │   │   └─Catalogs  
│   │   └─Backup Set 2014-02-27 091933  
│   │ ++      ├─Backup Files 2014-02-27 091933  
│   │ ++      └─Catalogs
```

What I want to do is to delete (by run a batch file in a daily scheduled task) all 'Backup Set' folders which date is older than a day leaving only the latest backup set for each user. It would be simple but there are also users which are not present in company for a few days. Thus their latest backup set should stay on the server in spite of the fact that it is outdated.
I have made such a batch:

```
forfiles /D -1 /P D:\User /M "Backup Set *" 
    /S /C "cmd /c if @ISDIR==TRUE (dir /b /a:d | find /c \"Backup Set\") 
    | (if not %1==\"1\" (rmdir /s /q @file))"
```

I don't know how to pass 'dir+find' result to 'if' command which follows it.
Any help would be appreciable. As well as any other open mind suggentions regarding the topic of this question/problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but I believe you should ask your question here at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/about), seems to fit better there.

Comment: This is a way-better-than-average first question AND the issue is specifically about syntax in batch-file scripting. IMHO it is appropriate for S.O. Unfortunately, I can't spend the time to figure out the answer. This would be much easier with the Unix/Linux toolset. If you're going to be doing more stuff this complex, it might be worth the trouble to install the Cygwin system to gain access to bash/ksh/find, etc. Good luck to all.

Comment: With the second directory under users (in your example) `Users > agnes.microt > AGNES-PC` - can you assume that each other users directory will follow the same format? if not, do they at least all end in `-PC`, and if so, is there any other folders in that directory that might end with `-PC` as well?

Comment: @ztirom  As you suggested I have asked my question also at ServerFault:  http://serverfault.com/questions/579347/desktop-backups-maintenance-on-a-network-share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,I managed to do this using PowerShell and basing on http://nisanthkv.blog.com/2012/07/30/removing-backup-folders-solution-1
Here is the result:
`Get-ChildItem MediaID.bin -Path D:\Users -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$_.DirectoryName} | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem "Backup Set*" -Path $_ | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {“Removing file $($_.FullName)”; Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse -Force}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to loop through the `Users` directories, for each user find the latest backup set, and then delete all others.

This will loop through all users - then loop through each users `username > *-PC` directory sorting by newest directory first - leave the first directory (newest) and delete every other.

Assuming the directory structure is `Users > username > *-PC`.

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('dir /B /A D D:\Users') (
    set cnt=0
    set pcdir=D:\Users\%%a
    for /f %%a in ('dir /B /A D /O-D "!pcdir!\*-PC"') do (
        if "!cnt!" NEQ "0" echo rmdir /S /Q
        set /c cnt+=1
    )
)
```

Obviously you need to remove the `echo` in the if command - just for testing so no directories are actually removed.

Note that I'm not able to test this at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately some of users' PC names (and thus also backup directory names automatically created by Windows Backup and Restore) does not end with '-PC'. For example: LICTORALPHA, SAMSUNGBK, etc.